# Convert from local time to GMT (World Clock application using nodatime)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, data-conversion, nodatime

I am trying to program a world clock using Nodatime, and I have searched the web for samples on how to use the library and I have read the documentation, and it says that the class Instant is simply a number of "ticks" since some arbitrary epoch the Unix epoch, which corresponds to midnight on January 1st 1970 UTC. Well, I empirically guessed that if I used as an Instant a GMT value, then I could calculate with it the time values for each time zone (creating the world clock), and it worked. The problem that I have, is that I don't know a simple way to calculate the GMT time (or GMT instant) from the local time, my time zone is "America/Mexico_City", so my question is, is there a shortcut already defined in Nodatime to get the GMT time from a local time, or in the other hand, is there a simple way to implement the "Instant GetInstantGMT()" function (the function has to take in count the day light saving time issues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for the "current" instant, such represents *now*, then use:

```
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
```

Calling it a "GMT instant" is redundant, since the `Instant` type is representing a universal moment in time without regard to time zone.  It is (mostly) equivalent to UTC - which is essentially the same as GMT.  In other words, you couldn't create an `Instant` that *wasn't* GMT.

Another way to think about an `Instant` is as if it were a `DateTime` whose `.Kind` property was permanently fixed to `DateTimeKind.Utc` and could not represent anything else.

Also, depending on exactly how your application is architected, you may find it useful to use the `IClock` interface instead:

```
IClock clock = SystemClock.Instance;
Instant now = clock.Now;
```

This would allow you to replace the system clock with a fake clock during unit testing.

Regarding how to go from a specific local time to an `Instant`, you would do something like this:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Mexico_City"];
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.InZoneLeniently(tz);
Instant instant = zdt.ToInstant();
```

Note that I used `InZoneLeniently` in the conversion.  This makes certain assumptions about how to translate from a local time that might be invalid or ambiguous due to [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).  This might be acceptable, or you might instead prefer to use `InZoneStrictly` which will throw exceptions, or `InZone` which allows you to pass a resolver function so you can provide your own logic.